# Manipulate deep nested arrays in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a rather convoluted array structure with 4 nested arrays that I need to manipulate with Mongoose/MongoDB. My code works but it doesn't get the beauty prize.

Right now i have a helper function that will look for an object of said ID and if it doesnt, it will $addToSet and return the array for further manipulation. This feels really clunky and i'm sure some query wizardry will fix this in a simple findOneAndUpdate().

The object structure is as follows:
bookshelf as an Array
Branch Object with an id and an array called Categories
Categories Object with an id and an array called Learnings
Learnings Object with an id and an array called Modules
Modules Object with an id and an array called Cards

It's setup this way due to the collection being one directional in terms of relationships and the documents have no parents. So for the sake of a bookmark functionality, i'm storing the whole path. So a Module could have several cards inside of it.

```
    // TODO can probably do this in some advanced query
    addtobookshelf: async function (req, res, next) {
        if(!req.body.branch)
            return next(boom.badRequest('No Branch id supplied.'));
        if(!req.body.category)
            return next(boom.badRequest('No Category id supplied.'));
        if(!req.body.learning)
            return next(boom.badRequest('No Learning id supplied.'));
        if(!req.body.module)
            return next(boom.badRequest('No Module id supplied.'));
        if(!req.body.card)
            return next(boom.badRequest('No Card id supplied.'));

        try{
            const saveslot = await SaveSlot.findOne({'owner':req.decoded._id});
            let branchObject = profile.manipulateBookmark(saveslot.bookshelf, req.body.branch);
            let categoryObject = profile.manipulateBookmark(branchObject.categories, req.body.category);
            let learningObject = profile.manipulateBookmark(categoryObject.learnings, req.body.learning);
            let moduleObject = profile.manipulateBookmark(learningObject.modules, req.body.module);
            // Finally add the card
            moduleObject.cards.addToSet(req.body.card);
            await saveslot.save();
            return res.status(200).json({message: 'succes', data: saveslot.bookshelf});
        } catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            return next(boom.internal('Woops, something went wrong. Sorry!'));
        }
    },
manipulateBookmark: function(objectArray, id){
        let obj;
        objectArray.forEach((element) => {
            if(element.id.toString() === id){
                obj = element;
                return;
            }
        });
        if(!obj){
            obj = objectArray.addToSet({id:id})[0];
        }
        return obj;
    },
```

It's readable so that counts but I'd like to improve my query skills.

[EDIT] Added data structure for clarification

```
{
    "bookshelf": [{
        "id": "59034709d44f340011bb8307",
        "categories": [{
            "id": "58c27aa7734d1d46588667ab",
            "learnings": [{
                "id": "5881d1f62fd76911007a4ae5",
                "modules": [{
                    "id": "5881d2962fd76911007a4ae8",
                    "cards": ["5881d5892fd76911007a4ae1"]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: It would be most helpful if you provided some sample data.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Added some sample data